# Retrieving array of data from POST CodeIgniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I'm using CodeIgniter and I'm having trouble retrieving an array from the input.
I have been searching but I can't solve this. The thing is i'm using a button to dynamically add text boxes.

(HTML from view.php)

```
<?php echo form_open('verifynovareceita'); ?>
(...)
<div id="ings">
       <p>Ingredients:</p>
       <input type="text" name="ings[]"/>
</div>

<input type="button" value="Add another ingrdient" name="add" onClick="addTextBox()">

(...)

<script type='text/javascript'>
    function addTextBox() {
        var ings = document.getElementById("ings");
        var input1 = document.createElement("input");
        input1.type = "text";       
        input1.name = "ings[]";
        ings.appendChild(input1);
    }
```

And the (visual) result is what it's expected. It creates as many inputs as I wanted. The problem is when it comes to retrieving the data from the POST array:

(PHP from controller)

```
  $ings = $this->input->post('ings');
  $row_count = count($ings);
```

$row_count has value 1, no matter how many text boxes existed.
Is there a problem with my code? Or is it the fact that i'm using form_open that makes it impossible to work?
I've tried to do the same thing, without codeigniter and it worked fine...
I appreciate any help! Thank you in advance.

Comment: first print_r($_POST['ings']); and check if it contains array or not because i run this example it works fine for me. May be your problem with this line $this->input->post('ings'); try to use $ings = $_POST['ings']; and check

Comment: Thank you for the answers. Unfortunatelly, i've tried what you sugested and it didn't work.
Adding 
        foreach($ings as $ing)
        {    echo $ing;    }
Only shows the first input of ings.

And trying 
       print_r($_POST['ings']);
Only gives the first ing as well (output: Array ( [0] => ing1 ))
I have no idea why this is happening...

Answer (score 1):

$this->input->post() function will not work up to mark if input is such type of array. if input is a such type of array you should use classic mehtod

`$ings = $_POST('ings');
  $row_count = count($ings);`

Answer (score 0):

For array inputs, you can use `$this->input->post()` as below. You have done correctly. You can use `foreach` as below to get all values from the array.

```
$ings = $this->input->post("ings");

foreach($ings as $ing)
{
  // your code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You Used ings[] as name. Now if you Retrieve   that with $this->input->post("ings");   it will always be a array.  Now use Foreach loop or For loop to get the array elements.